# How to incrementally reveal div tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have collection of `div` tags in the `form` tag, like this:

```
<form ...>
  <div id="div1"> ... </div>
  <div id="div2"> ... </div>
  ...
  ...
</form>
```

I want to display only `div1` in the visible area than when user presses `next`, the next div tag i.e. `div2` is displayed, and so on.

How can I achieve this?

I don't have much knowledge about different approaches available to do this, but I have some knowledge of Javascript, so any idea will be appreciated.

P.S. please provide sample code if possible, also I want client-side scripting.

Comment: Are you restricted to simple javascript, or a framework, such as jQuery, would be acceptable for a solution? Also, are you wanting any content loaded dynamically, or the full content of every `div` is fine to load on initial page?

Comment: @GuthMD no i am not restricted to any framework, also full content will be loaded on initial page.

Comment: Good solutions have been provided below. If you want to add some transition effects, at that point I'd recommend jQuery or the like, as the scripting can get pretty complex, otherwise.

Comment: @GuthMD can you give me an example for applying transition using jquery. i dont have much experience with jquery.

Comment: I'm not super experienced in jQuery myself, and often transitions take more than a trivial amount of code. Do a web search for jQuery transitions; there are a number of already built APIs, many free, for download.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some javascript and html demonstration that may help. Increment a current integer. You could deincrement with -- for back as well. There are many ways to do this. This is just one I thought of.

```
<img src="mynextbutton.jpg" onclick="showNext()" />
<form ...>
  <div id="Div0" style="display:inherit;"> ... </div>
  <div id="Div1" style="display:none;"> ... </div>
  <div id="Div2" style="display:none;"> ... </div>
  ...
  ...
</form>

//---------------------------------------------------

var currentDiv = 0;
function showNext()
{
     document.getElementById("Div"+currentDiv).style.display = "none";
     currentDiv ++;
     document.getElementById("Div"+currentDiv).style.display = "ihherit";


}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put all of the element IDs into an array, and then use that to get the next item you can remove the dependence on the ID numbering determining the order that they rotate in, and also prevent them from needing to follow such a rigid format.

```
//add all element IDs to this array
var elements = ["firstElementID","div2","someConentsID","lastElementID"]; 
var currentIndex = 0;

//ensure that the first item is visible at the start.

function next()
{
  //hide current item.
  document.getElementById(elements[currentIndex]).Style = "display:none";
  //move up the current index by one, wrapping so as to stay within array bounds.
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % elements.length;
  //show the new current item.
  document.getElementById(elements[currentIndex]).Style = "display:inline";
}
```

You can adjust the show/hide code to use JQuery, or whatever other mechanism you want.